# Count lines of scala code (omitting empty lines) in a directory, traversing any subdirectories

Tags: file-system, scala, io

I need to simply count lines of Scala code in a project, which includes some package(i.e. directory) hierarchy.

I'm not sure about the performance of the code below. Can you help improve it, if possible?

Also, in Java, we have `reduce()` in the Stream API, and I didn't find its counterpart in the Scala library, so ended with `foldLeft()`.

```
import java.io.File
import scala.io.Source

object CountLoc {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val parentDir: File = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"))

    def traverse(dir: File): Int = {
      val all = dir.list().map(f => new File(dir.getAbsolutePath + "/" + f))
      val srcs = all.filter(!_.isDirectory).filter(_.getName.endsWith(".scala"))
      val dirs = all.filter(_.isDirectory)
      srcs.foldLeft(0)((i, f) => i + Source.fromFile(f).getLines().filterNot(_.isEmpty).toList.size) +
        dirs.toList.foldLeft(0)((i,d) => i + traverse(d))
    }

    println("LOC: " + traverse(parentDir))
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining a function inside of a function? That's not a good idea for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of collecting all the source files in one sweep, and all the sub-directories in another sweep, you could move the `foldLeft()` to the top level and deal with each element as it is encountered.

```
def traverse(dir :File) :Int =
  dir.listFiles().foldLeft(0){ case (sum,file) =>
    if (file.isDirectory)
      sum + traverse(file)
    else if (file.getName.endsWith(".scala"))
      sum + io.Source.fromFile(file).getLines().count(_.nonEmpty)
    else
      sum
  }
```

Comment: A cool one! Great minimalistic approach.
( to get it running, I've added `import java.io.File` and changed `io.Source.fromFile` to `scala.io.Source.fromFile` )

Comment: and replaced `_.nonEmpty` with `_.trim.nonEmpty`